# Celery worker shut down

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd

My worker in celery automatically gets shut down and logs this message **worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)**, and doesn't do anything, I'm running a long running AI/ML tasks in celery

my celery config is something like this:

```
**app.conf.update(

    result_expires=None,  # Disable result expiration

    worker_max_tasks_per_child=500,  # Disable limiting the number of tasks each worker can execute before it's replaced

    worker_prefetch_multiplier=0,  # Disable prefetching tasks

    worker_concurrency=1,  # Use all available CPU cores for concurrency

    worker_disable_rate_limits=True,  # Disable rate limits for tasks

    task_track_started=True,  # Track started tasks

    task_soft_time_limit=None,  # Disable soft time limit for tasks

    task_time_limit=None,  # Disable hard time limit for tasks

    worker_max_memory_per_child=None,  # Disable memory limit for worker processes

    task_acks_late=True,

    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,  # Enable broker connection retries on startup

)**
```

Sometimes it shuts down and sometimes it doesn't can anyone say something